# How add tabs in react-native IOS using rn-viewpager

Tags: ios, reactjs, tabs, react-native

I am using `rn-viewpager` for tabs in `react-native`. But I am having issues in opening new page on each tab selected.

I am using following link: [react-native-viewpager](https://github.com/jr-k/React-Native-ViewPager)

```
export default class ViewPagerPage extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <IndicatorViewPager
                        indicatorPosition="top"
                        style={{flex:1, paddingTop:20, backgroundColor:'white'}}
                        indicator={this._renderTitleIndicator()}
                    >
                        <View style={{backgroundColor:'cadetblue'}}>
                            <Text>page one</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor:'cornflowerblue'}}>
                            <Text>page two</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{backgroundColor:'#1AA094'}}>
                            <Text>page three</Text>
                        </View>
                    </IndicatorViewPager>


                </View>
            );
        }

        _renderTitleIndicator() {
            return <PagerTitleIndicator titles={['Page1', 'Page2', 'Page3']} />;
        }


            return (
                <PagerTabIndicator
                    tabs={tabs}
                    textStyle={{color:'#999'}}
                    selectedTextStyle={{color:'#111'}}
                    iconStyle={{width:25, height:25, tintColor:'#999'}}
                    selectedIconStyle={{width:25, height:25, tintColor:'#111'}}
                />
            );
        }

    }
```

I want to open page.js file on click of every tab.

Comment: Your code is broken. The last return is not in a class method.

Comment: @BK19 same problem